# Using the system command with an ampersand at the end isn't running the process in the background

Tags: php

I'm making a simple call to restore a mysql backup that takes about 45 minutes to complete on one of my servers.

```
system("mysql -u$user -p$pass $db < '$file' &");
```

Running it that way locks my browser and I have to wait until it's finished before I can do anything.  This works fine on my other server.  What settings could be preventing that from working on the first server?

Comment: This looks like on the one server system is waiting for the background task to complete, while on the other it doesn't. What Operating Systems are the two servers? Does the PHP version differ? Have you tried to put the command into a shell script and invoke it instead?

Comment: The two servers are so ridiculously different I don't even know where to start.  Which is why I was wondering if anyone knew of something specific that would cause this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still have the "handle" to the output pipes (stdout && stderr) which prevents backgrounding fully.

append a `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the end.

Comment: I was under the impression that there was no output to redirect from that command.

Comment: It does not matter the program to be run outputs anything - it might do that, thus the output pipes are open.